How to Programmatically Generate Wallets for the TON Network in a Telegram Bot?
I'm developing a Telegram bot that generates wallets for the TON (The Open Network) blockchain. The goal is to allow users to create valid TON wallets and provide them with the necessary credentials, such as the wallet address and seed phrase, that can be used with Tonkeeper or other TON-compatible wallets.
What I've Tried:

Using nacl and mnemonic Libraries:
mnemonic: To generate a 24-word seed phrase.
nacl: To derive a private key and public key from the seed.
Sample Code:


import os
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from mnemonic import Mnemonic
from nacl.signing import SigningKey
from nacl.encoding import RawEncoder
from nacl.hash import blake2b
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN')

if not TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN:
    raise ValueError("The Telegram bot token was not found. Make sure it's in the .env file.")

def generate_wallet():
    mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
    seed_phrase = mnemo.generate(strength=256)  # 24 words
    seed = mnemo.to_seed(seed_phrase)
    signing_key = SigningKey(seed[:32])
    verify_key = signing_key.verify_key
    public_key_bytes = verify_key.encode(RawEncoder)
    address = blake2b(public_key_bytes, digest_size=32, encoder=RawEncoder).hex()
    wallet_private_key = signing_key.encode().hex()
    return address, wallet_private_key, seed_phrase

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello! Use /newwallet to generate a new TON wallet.')

async def new_wallet(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    try:
        wallet_address, wallet_private_key, seed_phrase = generate_wallet()
        await update.message.reply_text(
            f'✅ Generated new wallet:\n\n'
            f'**Address:** `{wallet_address}`\n\n'
            f'**Seed Phrase:** `{seed_phrase}`\n\n'
            f'⚠️ Make sure to save this seed phrase using pen and paper only. '
            f'Do NOT copy-paste it anywhere. You could also import it to your wallet. '
            f'After you finish saving/importing the wallet credentials, delete this message. '
            f'The bot will not display this information again.',
            parse_mode='Markdown'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        await update.message.reply_text(f'Error generating the wallet: {e}')

def main() -> None:
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("newwallet", new_wallet))
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Using TON-Client Library:
Attempted to use ton-client-py to generate keys, but faced issues with unavailable functions and import errors.
Sample Code:


import os
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from tonclient.client import TonClient, DEVNET_BASE_URLS, ClientConfig
from tonclient.crypto import generate_random_sign_keys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN')

if not TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN:
    raise ValueError("The Telegram bot token was not found. Make sure it's in the .env file.")

client = TonClient(config=ClientConfig(network={'server_address': DEVNET_BASE_URLS}))

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello! Use /newwallet to generate a new TON wallet.')

async def new_wallet(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    try:
        key_pair = generate_random_sign_keys(client)
        wallet_address = key_pair.public
        wallet_private_key = key_pair.secret
        await update.message.reply_text(
            f'✅ Generated new wallet:\n\n'
            f'**Address:** `{wallet_address}`\n\n'
            f'**Private Key:** `{wallet_private_key}`\n\n'
            f'⚠️ Make sure to save this information securely.',
            parse_mode='Markdown'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        await update.message.reply_text(f'Error generating the wallet: {e}')

def main() -> None:
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("newwallet", new_wallet))
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Issues Faced:
**Invalid Wallets**:
    Wallet addresses and seed phrases generated are not recognized by Tonkeeper.

**Library Limitations**:
    Difficulty in finding up-to-date and comprehensive libraries for generating TON wallets programmatically.
    ton-client-py provided several import errors and lacked the expected functionalities.

**Documentation**:
    Limited documentation and examples for working with TON wallet generation and integration with Tonkeeper.

Question:
- How can I generate a valid TON wallet programmatically in Python that is compatible with Tonkeeper?
- Are there any recommended libraries or APIs that provide robust support for TON wallet generation?
Could you provide a working example or guide on how to achieve this?

